# Passing XML between .NET and native c++

Tags: c#, c++, xml

I have a project in native c++ that currently communicates with a c# project through COM. I'd like to replace COM with a c++\cli wrapper. Both projects use XML, and pass it back and forth using COM Variant. If I switched to a c++/cli wrapper, what could I use to pass XML between the layers?

Comment: do you mean the XML source, or the parsed DOM-like structure? if source, why not just string?

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll go with a string.

Comment: You may find it useful to use the methods from here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/OrcasMarshalAs.aspx (you'll definitely need to convert `std::wstring` <--> `System.String`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we had a similar arrangement and we switched to use a simple socket to pass the messages. In our case it was a native c/c++ app and a managed app - so two processes. Gave us the advantage to put them on separate PCs as well. If the native project is just a DLL you call into you might just want to add a `SendMessage` interface to pass the XML message as string through.